# use select case condition with SQL query statement in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I try to use select case statement with SQL statement
I have 4 columns when the lbl1.text equal 1 then x = "column1" and put this value in the SQL statement 
when I try this code

```
 Dim x As String
    Select Case lbl1.Text
        Case 1
            x = "column1"
        Case 2
            x = " column2"
        Case 3
            x = " column3"
        Case 4
            x = " column4"
            DGV1.Columns.Clear()
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Clear()
            DGV1.Visible = True
            Dim comm2 As New SqlCommand
            comm2.CommandText = Nothing
            DGV1.Refresh()
            comm2.CommandText = "select first_name,last_name,age from students where " + x + "=" + "yes" + ""
            comm2.Connection = sqlconn
            sqlconn.Open()
            dr2 = comm2.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(dr2)
            DGV1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
            DGV1.DataSource = dt
            DGV1.Refresh()
            sqlconn.Close()
            DGV1.Visible = True
            comm2.Dispose()
    End Select
```

and when **lbl1.text = 1 or 2 or 3** it doesn't run the SQL statement but when the **lbl1.text = 4** it's run SQL statement
can any one help me in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, i just don't know if the break is the right syntax, but i guarantee you that this is the right code

`   Dim x As String
    Select Case lbl1.Text
        Case 1
            x = "column1"

```
    Case 2
        x = " column2"

    Case 3
        x = " column3"

    Case 4
        x = " column4"

End Select
        DGV1.Columns.Clear()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Clear()
        DGV1.Visible = True
        Dim comm2 As New SqlCommand
        comm2.CommandText = Nothing
        DGV1.Refresh()
        comm2.CommandText = "select first_name,last_name,age from students where " + x + "=" + "yes" + ""
        comm2.Connection = sqlconn
        sqlconn.Open()
        dr2 = comm2.ExecuteReader
        dt.Load(dr2)
        DGV1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        DGV1.DataSource = dt
        DGV1.Refresh()
        sqlconn.Close()
        DGV1.Visible = True
        comm2.Dispose()`
```